# Where is Capybara's #must_have_content defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, minitest

I use Capybara with Minitest and I'm confused as to where some of the assertions come from. Capybara docs give only one example, i.e. [`#must_have_content`](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#using-capybara-with-minitestspec), which I decided to take as a point of reference. Closest I got is the `minitest-rails-capybara` gem, which suggests that the method is an extension of `assert_content`, however the lines are all commented out.

[image]

Can anyone help to explain how this works? Does Minitest/Capybara decode this at some point? If so, why is it implemented like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header "Using Capybara with Minitest::Spec" contains a hint :) Check https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/minitest/spec.rb#L8 ...

Comment: It does seem to be it, although I am now confused as to what is `minitest-rails-capybara` gem even for. It seems like it's mostly just a bunch of comments (`capybara.rb` file anyway). Thank you.

Comment: @sloneorzeszki `minitest-rails-capybara` pulls in some gems (`minitest-rails`, `minitest-capybara`, and `minitest-metadata`), and then sets up things like switching the driver in use based on :js metadata attached to the test.  The issue is that the `minitest-capybara`, which did the actual assertion definitions, gem became obsolete when Capybara started including all the previous minitest assertions (and more) natively.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Thanks, great to hear from the author of the gem himself :) I found [this](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails-capybara/commit/e317485764ab2a904998625227032de9cb5a2c43#diff-c804bd70634c0a120f3342211f813633) commit which explains that it's pretty much just documentation. So what is the role of `minitest-rails-capybara` currently? Is it still required to make Capybara work with Minitest? I have it in my client's Gemfile (project started on Rails 1 and includes some legacy code here and there), so I'm not sure if I still have to keep it in there.

Comment: @sloneorzeszki It's not required to use capybara with minitest, but it may be required for the rails/test setup stuff - https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails-capybara/blob/master/lib/minitest/rails/capybara.rb#L18 - depending on how exactly your tests are written, and what other setup you're doing yourself - easy way to find out is to remove the gem and see what breaks.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Thank you :)